# storing persistant data at farm level for a timer job

Tags: 2010, application-pages, properties, farm

Ive created a timer job and a application page so i can set some custom values that the timer job uses.  Im currently storing the values in the farm.properties hastable so that the timer job can access them.  The data levels are low so i dont think this will be a problem, but im confused about whether to use the properties hashtable or the propertybag.  Can someone give me a quick heads up on the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SPFarm.Properties hashtable is sometimes referred to as the Property Bag as well (e.g. the [Property Bag Settings tool](http://pbs2010.codeplex.com/) is just a UI for the .Properties collection). So unless you are referring to something different, they are the same thing.